# Add email addresses to already registered users

Tags: users, email, account

my website users register with phone number OTP. That's why they have no email address in their accounts. Today I need email address in user accounts. I use this code to add email address for new user registrations.

```
add_action("user_register", function ($user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    if (empty($user->data->user_email)) {
        $args = array(
            "ID"         => $user->id,
            "user_email" => uniqid() . "@example.com",
        );
        wp_update_user( $args );
    }
});
add_filter( 'bnfw_trigger_insert_post', '__return_true' );
```

But I have about 3000 users that need email address in their accounts if empty . How can I do this automatically . Can make above code to work for already registered user.

*and above code generate email like this    62961a20c7f2a@exmaple.com .how can use "username" instead of uniqid()*

**my new code according to answer**

```
      // The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( ['number' => 3500, 'paged' => 1] );

// if users were found
if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
    // then for each user
    foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {
        // if it already has an email, skip it
        if ( ! empty( $user->user_email ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        // otherwise, add an email here...
         $args = array(
            "ID"         => $user->id,
            "user_email" => $user->user_login . "@example.com",
        );
        wp_update_user( $args );
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the updated code has `$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );`, it's already getting the `$user` from the user query in the loop, so that line is unnecessary. It's also unclear where this code is located and when it runs, I suspect you've confused my 2 pieces of code and combined them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Doing This For a Single User In The `user_register` Filter

Instead of using `get_userdata` in your filter, fetch the user itself as a `WP_User` object via `get_user_by`:

```php
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
```

This gives you access to all of the fields of `WP_User` directly, e.g.:

```php
echo $user->user_login;
```

Which you can then plug into your code

### Doing this for all the other users

You should use `WP_User_Query` to fetch an array of users that do not have emails ( assuming the email is an empty string ). This would not happen inside your filter and is a separate independent piece of code.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/

Here's an example from the docs that loops through every user with a blank email and displays their name:

```php
// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( [] );

// if users were found
if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
    // then for each user
    foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {
        // if it already has an email, skip it
        if ( ! empty( $user->user_email ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        // otherwise, add an email here...
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

You can remove the `echo` and replace it with your check that tests the email is empty and updates the user.

Note that since you have a lot of users, you may need to set `'number' => 200, 'paged' => 1,` in the `WP_User_Query` arguments, and re-run the loop several times with `paged` set to higher numbers. This is to avoid running out of memory.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I added my new code according to your answer. But when I run this code nothing happens

Comment: I have adjusted my answer. Based on your question edit you've confused the two sections of my code and merged them to create new code that is confusing and does not do what I said. Note that none of my code is a copy paste solution, it requires that you read and understand the answer

Comment: none of my code is a copy paste solution : yes that's why I never want you to answer my questions. XD. But today you saved my day. Thank you soo much Tom. I updated working code

Comment: woow this updated all emails. even not empty

Comment: your updated code does not include a check to see if the user has an empty email. My answers code includes such a check and a `continue;` statement so that it skips users that already have an email set

Comment: the general gist is: fetch all users using `WP_User_Query`, then for each `$user` it found, if it's got an email `continue`/skip, otherwise give it an email

Comment: sorry you are right it was my stupidness. everything worked except pagenation that's why I updated all at once. Thank you very much.

Comment: if you're able to update all at once then go ahead and skip pagination :) and it's easy enough mistake you're not stupid